# How to print employee details like employee phone num, department etc in odoo qweb report

Tags: report, odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I want to print employee details from hr.employee model to my qweb report(Purchase Requisition).

I am trying the code like following:

```
                            <tr>
                                <td style="border:1px solid #000;padding-left:5px">Department:<span t-esc="o.user_id.partner_id.department_id.name"/></td>
                                <td style="border:1px solid #000;padding-left:5px"> </td></tr>
```

And facing this error:
Error to render compiling AST
AttributeError: 'res.partner' object has no attribute 'department_id'

I understood that my current object does'nt contain department_id field. Then how can I get this employee details from hr.employee model for the logged in user??

Any help is highly appreciated and I am using odoo 10. Thanks!

Comment: Just check the existing modules in odoo apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the code of the hr module](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/91ca846447628084f5a089e986319ef18581ddf2/addons/hr/models/res_users.py#L12), you most likely need to use:

```xml
<span t-esc="', '.join(o.user_id.mapped('employee_ids.department_id.display_name'))"/>
```

Comment: Many thanks for replying. This is working only for department_id, I want to print full contact details like work mobile, work location, work email etc. I am new to Odoo please share how I can print other fields (I have installed Employee module and edited employee details there). Thanks again!

Comment: If I give mobile_phone at the place of department_id then the following error is raised.: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_mapped_func'

Error to render compiling AST
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_mapped_func'
Template: 844
Path: /templates/t/t/t/t/div[2]/table[1]/tr[4]/td[1]/span
Node: <span t-esc="', '.join(o.user_id.mapped('employee_ids.mobile_phone.name'))"/>

Comment: `.mapped()` will return a recordset only if the target field is relational. Otherwise it returns a `list()`, and lists don't have `.mapped()`. Just check [the docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/orm.html#odoo.models.Model.mapped)

Comment: Understood your point dear Yajo, still im trying how to achieve my desired result. If you know any tutorial which covers how to get other table data in qweb please tell me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I end up with the following solution which worked for me.

For relational fields use @Yajo solution:

```
<span t-esc="','.join(o.user_id.mapped('employee_ids.department_id.display_name'))" />
```

For other fields use this:

```
<span t-esc="request.env.user.employee_ids.mobile_phone" />
```

Thanks for your kind replies!